# Jquery pattern match escaping not displaying custom error message

Tags: jquery

My first post!

I've been struggling with a building 2 jquery variables that are basically used to:

1. Ensure the regex pattern is followed
2. Compare fields and not submit until both are matched.

The first field which loads in HTML is changed and the second dynamically added:

```
$('#pass').on('input', function () {
   $("#pass").replaceWith(ba);
   $("#prd").html('New Account Password<span class="small">Your New Account Password</span>');
   $("#pass").focus();
   var newTextBoxDivc = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({
       "id": "TextBoxDivc"
   }).css({
       "display": "inline",
       "position": "relative"
   });
   newTextBoxDivc.after().html(bb);
   newTextBoxDivc.appendTo("#op");
});

var bb = ("<label>Confirm New Password</label><span class='small'>Confirm Your New Password</span><input type='text' name='passa' id='passa' required pattern='(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\\w{6,20}' onchange='this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? \'Your passwords do not match please enter the same password as above\' : \'\');' oncopy='return false' onpaste='return false' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off'>");

var ba = ("<input type='text' name='pass' id='pass' required pattern='(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\\w{6,20}' oncopy='return false' onpaste='return false' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' onchange='this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? \'To create a strong password for your account use a mix of at least 6 characters that includes at least one UPPERCASE letter (A-Z) and at least one number (0-9)\' : \'\'); if(this.checkValidity()) formEley.passa.pattern = this.value;'>");
```

JFiddle says the code is fine and when pressing the submit button it does say "You must use this format"...so the check for the pattern seems to be ok...but it's not displaying the custom error message.

Been pulling my hair out for the past 4 hours on it.

Any and all help most welcomed!!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesMarz/db1qa83f/

Comment: If you have a JSFiddle, then link it!

Comment: I don't have a jsfiddle account. Just tested the core code there. Been trying to open one since your post but it seems there's problems with their registration. Keeps telling me someone with the mail is already registered which I'm not and then when I try to reset the password it says there is not account!??! AArrrggghhh...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesMarz/db1qa83f/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't look like the code you posted here. It's missing the backslashes on the innermost apostrophes (3 levels of string nesting, yikes) and one of the conditional expressions is missing the `: ''` part.

Comment: I've been trying a million combinations Wumpus...sorry for the confusion. I'll update the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with an alternative approach. Basically I think it's a problem for changevalidity to be dynamically written with a custom error message from a variable.

Actually even if you take out the variables (copy the html of bb and ba) and instead write this directly into the code it's still a no go...so maybe this is simply a bug or limit at this time.

Anyone have any input. Feel free to jump in and share.

Instead I've stripped it all down and performed the checks in a function.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var email = $('#mail').val();
var email_regex = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
```

From there simply perform the check.

```
if (!email.match(email_regex) || email.length == 0) {
$("#mail").focus();
```

Then write the error message directly onto the page.

```
$(".holdcontent").html("<h1>Error</h1<p class='p4'>Please check your email address and verify that you have entered your email details correctly.</p>");
return false;
```

}

The return false is of course to prevent the form being submitted :)

Ok guys. First post and actually turned into my first solution as well. Pity I can't +1 for myself then? ;)